# HTML changes not reflected in django-cms

Tags: python, html, django, django-cms

I was working on an old django-cms project and was trying to edit `base.html` file and no changes are reflected when I reload the page.

But if I delete all the lines in that file the django runserver refuses to start showing error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The 'js' and 'css' sekizai namespaces must be present in each template, - or a template it inherits from - defined in CMS_TEMPLATES. I can't find the namespaces in 'project/cms/home.html'.
```

They why isn't other changes like adding a new class not reflected in the page reload or server restart.

NOTE:
The project is working good as it is. I was trying to modify it a little bit. Changes I made in the css pages are getting reflected when I reload the page. Issue is only when I try to edit HTML pages

Answer (score 1):

For `base.html`, you need to have `{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}` in the file. Add `{% render_block "css" %}` to `<head></head>` and `{% render_block "js" %}` somewhere between `<body></body>`. Depending on the template files that inherit from `base.html`, certain portions may have been overwritten. For example, if you had:

```
{# base.html #}
{% block content %}
    <div class="example-class"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

But in another file say:

```
{# layout.html #}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

The div would not appear.

If however, you are talking about missing CSS files, you still need to include them in `<head>` for it to be displayed. `render_block "css"` is for django-cms css files that are included in plugins etc. I usually use a LESS or SCSS compiler to include CSS into my projects.

Hope that helps. Post more details for a better diagnosis.

Comment: The project is working good as it is. I was trying to modify it a little bit. Changes I made in the css pages are getting reflected when I reload the page. Issue is only when I try to edit HTML pages. Also I was trying to add a class in the html tag.

Comment: What do you mean by trying to edit HTML pages? What pages are these? Are you adding a dynamic class to the html tag?

Comment: I just added a class 'sdf' to <html> class. No not dynamic.

Comment: Apologies, I think you cannot add a class to the html tag according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html. Try adding the class to <body> instead.

Comment: Actually there was already some classes there and I tried to add one; even if I add one to <body> its not working.

Comment: Strange, could you post the code somewhere like Plunker for a quick look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75365/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-mrkre).